# How can I fix yowsup stream: code 503 error?

Tags: python, yowsup

I'm running presence subscription for too many numbers via yowsup-cli. But after a while I get stream:error code = "503" error. This usually happens after 15 minutes. How can I solve this problem?

I'm getting this error:

```
{
  "data": "D 2020-04-24 01:05:52,234 yowsup.layers.logger.layer - rx:\n<stream:error code=\"503\" />\nE 2020-04-24 01:05:52,235 yowsup.layers.network.dispatcher.dispatcher_asyncore - Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py\", line 83, in read\n    obj.handle_read_event()\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py\", line 449, in handle_read_event\n    self.handle_read()\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/network/dispatcher/dispatcher_asyncore.py\", line 48, in handle_read\n    self.connectionCallbacks.onRecvData(data)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/network/layer.py\", line 107, in onRecvData\n    self.receive(data)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/network/layer.py\", line 110, in receive\n    self.toUpper(data)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/__init__.py\", line 79, in toUpper\n    self.__upper.receive(data)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/noise/layer_noise_segments.py\", line 39, in receive\n    self.toUpper(bytes(data))\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/__init__.py\", line 79, in toUpper\n    self.__upper.receive(data)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/noise/layer.py\", line 181, in receive\n    self._flush_incoming_buffer()\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/noise/layer.py\", line 169, in _flush_incoming_buffer\n    self.toUpper(self._wa_noiseprotocol.receive())\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/__init__.py\", line 79, in toUpper\n    self.__upper.receive(data)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/coder/layer.py\", line 21, in receive\n    self.toUpper(node)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/__init__.py\", line 79, in toUpper\n    self.__upper.receive(data)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/logger/layer.py\", line 14, in receive\n    self.toUpper(data)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/__init__.py\", line 79, in toUpper\n    self.__upper.receive(data)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/axolotl/layer_control.py\", line 35, in receive\n    self.toUpper(protocolTreeNode)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/__init__.py\", line 79, in toUpper\n    self.__upper.receive(data)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/__init__.py\", line 194, in receive\n    s.receive(data)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/axolotl/layer_receive.py\", line 35, in receive\n    self.toUpper(protocolTreeNode)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/__init__.py\", line 79, in toUpper\n    self.__upper.receive(data)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/__init__.py\", line 194, in receive\n    s.receive(data)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/__init__.py\", line 130, in receive\n    recv(node)\n  File \"/var/www/html/yowsup/yowsup/layers/auth/layer_authentication.py\", line 67, in handleStreamError\n    raise NotImplementedError(\"Unhandled stream:error node:\n%s\" % node)\nNotImplementedError: Unhandled stream:error node:\n<stream:error code=\"503\" />\n\nD 2020-04-24 01:05:52,235 yowsup.layers.network.dispatcher.dispatcher_asyncore - handle_close\nD 2020-04-24 01:05:52,235 yowsup.layers.network.layer - Disconnected",
  "deb": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[503](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503) error often means that the server cannot respond at that moment. There are many reasons for the error, but if you just want to go through with the request, you can have an if statement for when the server returns a 503 error, and redo the request in a bit until it responds with a 200.

Comment: Do you know about yowsup? How can I do this in yowsup?

Comment: depends on your code and where you make the request. Yowsup shouldn't be different than other APIs.